# Why I cannot delete properly from a List and ListView?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, listview

I have a ListView in my Form.
I want to delete a row, but when I select one and delete it, later it comes back and I can't delete from the List where data comes from.
Why is that?

```
Pontszam pt = new Pontszam();
List<int> pontszamook = new List<int>();
List<string> nevek = new List<string>();
List<string> idk = new List<string>();
List<string> ptList = new List<string>();
int osszSor = 0;

public int sorokSzama()
{
    osszSor = pt.select().Count;
    return osszSor;
}

private void Ponttablazat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    osszSor = sorokSzama();
    ptList = pt.select();
    listScore.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < osszSor; i++) 
    {
        string[] adatok = ptList[i].Split(';');
        idk.Add(adatok[0]);
        nevek.Add(adatok[1]);
        pontszamook.Add(Convert.ToInt32(adatok[2]));
        var row = new string[] { nevek[i], Convert.ToString(pontszamook[i]) };
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(idk[i]);
        lvi.SubItems.AddRange(row);
        listScore.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}

private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listScore.SelectedItems != null) 
    {
        for (int i = listScore.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            ListViewItem itm = listScore.SelectedItems[i];
            int indeX = itm.Index; 
            listScore.Items[itm.Index].Remove();
            ptList[indeX] = null;
            idk[indeX] = null;
            nevek[indeX] = null;
            pontszamook[indeX] = -1;
            pt.deletetRow(itm.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (listScore.SelectedItems != null) { for (int i = listScore.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ListViewItem itm = listScore.SelectedItems[i]; int indeX = itm.Index; listScore.Items[itm.Index].Remove(); ptList[indeX] = null; idk[indeX] = null; nevek[indeX] = null; pontszamook[indeX] = -1; pt.deletetRow(itm.Index); } } }

Comment: Don't post your code in comments. I needed - edit the question

Comment: you have 3 options - 1. delete from list and listview; 2. Delete from list and repopulate listview; 3. Create some binding so when you delete from listview it will be deleted from the list